# I Want to write a formula in salesforce which can do the following Task

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

There are 3 users A,B and C
I want to check which user is accessing the org right now and  want to display the name of the user as result in a text box.
Im trying to compare the user name with the current user but not able to get the current user name

```
ala__Business__r.ala__ChargeEngineer__r.Name  = CURRENT USER
```

Im not able to compare the user name i want to compare with my current user.
Please guide me as Im new to salesforce.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `$User.FirstName & " " & $User.LastName`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked..
Thankyou for the help. :)